# Is the code below correct? how to fix this code

Tags: c

Is the code below correct?

```
 char *make_file_name(char *base)
 {
 char *file_name = strdup(base);
 strcat(file_name, ".pcap")
 return file_name;
}
```

how to fix it

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] a good question and how to create a [mcve]. Edit the question and use the `{}` button in the question editor toolbar to format the code.

Comment: No, it is not. Do not use `strdup` here. Duplicate the string by hand and make sure to allocate enough space to fit the original string *and* the suffix.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the code below correct?

No. Explanation:

```
char *make_file_name(char *base)
{
 char *file_name = strdup(base); // 1
 strcat(file_name, ".pcap")      // 2
 return file_name;
}
```

1. `file_name` now points to a memory area just big enough to hold a string of the same length as the string pointed out by `base`.
2. You here try to concatenate `file_name` and `".pcap"` - but there is not enough space so it'll write out of bounds, with *undefined behavior* as a result.

The fix is to allocate enough memory for both strings:

```
char *make_file_name(const char *base) // may as well make it const
{
 size_t blen = strlen(base);
 char *file_name = malloc(blen + 5 + 1);    // blen + strlen(".pcap") + 1 for `\0`
 if(!file_name) return NULL;
 memcpy(file_name, base, blen);
 memcpy(file_name + blen, ".pcap", 5 + 1);
 return file_name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`strdup()` allocates memory for the size of `base` + 1 and copies `base` into that allocated memory.

In your code, when you call `strcat()`, there is not enough space to concatenate `file_name` with `".pcap"`. As a result a out-of-bounds write will occur which invokes undefined behavior.

To fix this you must allocate enough memory for both strings:

```
char *make_file_name(const char *base)
{
     char *file_name  = malloc(strlen(base) + 5 + 1);

     if (file_name != NULL) {
         strcpy(file_name, base);
         strcat(file_name, ".pcap");
     }

     return file_name;
}
```

Remember to `free()` the memory once you are done with it:

```
char *str = make_file_name("file1");
// use str
free(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [asprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/asprintf) function:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

char* make_file_name(const char* base) {
  char* buffer = NULL;
  asprintf(&buffer, "%s.pcap", base);
  return buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate enough memory before using `strdup`. You can do this:

```
char *file_name  = malloc(strlen(base) + 6);
```

before the `if` condition then after the function is done, you need to deallocate the memory using `free()`